# is there a way to convert a template's substitution failure into a bool value (true/false) or tags (std::true_type/std::false_type)

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

I am "playing" a little with SFINAE in C++17-style and I am trying to achieve a result in which substitution failure instead of just causing the compiler to move to the next case, causes the "compiler" (rather, a class that underwent such attempt) to report (through `false`/`std::false_type`) that substitution failed, and only then the compiler moves to the next case.

My current attempts boiled down to something like that:

```
template <typename T>
class logic_value
{
    static constexpr bool result = std::is_same<
        std::enable_if_t<T, std::true_type>,
        std::true_type>;
};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool lv = logic_value<T>::result;
```

(usage example:)

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<
    lv<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())> /* has plus operator */ 
    && 
    (lv<decltype(std::declval<T>().func_foo())> || lv<decltype(std::declval<T>().func_bar())>) /*has either func_foo() or func_bar() */ 
    &&
    lv<T&> /* can have a reference */
    && 
    (!lv<decltype(std::declval<T>().func_foobar())>) /* does NOT have a func_foobar() */
, T> const & Ioo(T const &);
```

but it doesn't work as i imagined it would... :/ 
Especially tricky is a case when I am using `logic not`(`!`) operator to ensure that something within a tested type, doesn't exist.

Comment: I think you want `std::experimental::is_detected`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is with the detection idiom, you want [`is_detected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) with the appropriate aliases.

In your specific case:

```
template <typename T> using has_plus_t = decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>());
template <typename T> using func_foo_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().func_foo());
template <typename T> using func_bar_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().func_bar());
template <typename T> using func_foobar_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().func_foobar());

template <typename T>
enable_if_t<
    is_detected_v<has_plus_t, T>
    && 
    (is_detected_v<func_foo_t, T> || is_detected_v<func_bar_t, T>)
    &&
    is_detected_v<add_lvalue_reference_t, T>
    && 
    !is_detected_v<func_foobar_t, T>
, T> const & Ioo(T const &);
```

You can't have the expressions you want to test in this context, because as soon as one fails the whole thing fails.Your logic allows for, and requires, certain expressions failing - so you need the control the instantiation of all of these expressions. That's what the detection idiom is for.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your `logical_value` is, that you don't offer the compiler an alternative path in case that an substitution error occurs.

I do these things like this:

```
#include <utility>
#include <array>

template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto check_addition(int) -> decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<U>() , std::true_type{});

template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr std::false_type check_addition(...);

template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool can_add = decltype(check_addition<T, U>(0))::value;

int main() {

    static_assert(can_add<int, float>);
    static_assert(!can_add<std::string, float>);

}
```

The idea is to exploit two overloads, one with a specific type argument (`int` in my case), and one with an ellipsis. When we call that overloaded function with an `int` as parameter, the compiler will first check the `int` overload where it has to perform the desired check.

The comma operator is used to provide `true_type` as return type in cast the check completes successfully.

If the first overload SFINAE-fails, the second overload is chosen which always returns a `false_type`.